# Understanding router specs correctly?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, 802.11ac

I'm trying to better understand router specs.

Let's say a user has 100Mbps speed from their ISP.  If they have 2 devices attached via WiFi 802.11ac, it seems like AC1200 is more than adequate to meet their needs.

I came to this conclusion after studying:
https://wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11ac

In the chart on that page, it states that AC1200 supports 867Mbps with 2 streams on the 5GHz frequency.  Well, that's much more than the 100Mbps provided by their ISP.

Am I understanding things correctly?

Comment: yes, more or less. you could saturate 100mbps with just 802.11n (not that most consumer grade hardware ever actually meets theoretical specs, but...). Is there a particular question you have?

Comment: Theoretical throughput is a lot different than achieved throughput. But, technically you are correct. Even if you get 50% of the theoretical throughput you’re still faster than your internet connection. It’s still not faster and less reliable than a wired gigabit network if you intend to share files between computers or a media server on your network.

Comment: @Appleoddity Thanks.  I think that answers it.  Feel free to make an answer out of your comment.